# Changing associate array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I've inherited the following code:

```
  $sql_data_array = array('customers_id' => $customer_id,
                      'customers_name' => $order->customer['cname'],
                      'orders_status' => $order->info['order_status'],
                      'currency_value' => $order->info['currency_value']);
```

What I need t do is to see if customer_status=0, and if so make currency_value = "yes".

However I'm not sure if I should do this before or after the above statement and I'm not entirely clear on what is going on above to know how to do it?

I know the => operator deals with associative arrays but I'm a bit lost beyond that.  Any help on this in both what to do and explaining what is going on?

Comment: From where you take this code.?

Comment: Your are just creating an `array` not an `associative array` which had keys defined by yourself

Comment: It's from an OS Commerce website I inherited.  I thought => dealt with associative arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your given array structure it looks like the array format is like in these two possible manner:-

```
1.Array
  (
     [customers_id] => customer id
     [customers_name] => name
     [orders_status] => 0
     [currency_value] => some digit
   )

2. Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [customers_id] => customer id
                    [customers_name] => name
                    [orders_status] => 0
                    [currency_value] => some digit
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [customers_id] => customer id
                    [customers_name] => name
                    [orders_status] => yes/no
                    [currency_value] => some digit
                )

        )
```

If is it like first one then use :-

```
if($sql_data_array['orders_status'] == 0){
    $sql_data_array['currency_value'] = 'yes';
}
```

If is it like second one then use :-

```
foreach ($sql_data_array1 as $key => $sql_data_arr){
    if($sql_data_arr['orders_status'] == 0){
        $sql_data_array1[$key]['currency_value'] = 'yes';
    }else{
    $sql_data_array1[$key]['currency_value'] = 'no';
}
}
```

Output is :-

```
1. Array
    (
        [customers_id] => customer id
        [customers_name] => name
        [orders_status] => 0
        [currency_value] => yes
    )

2. Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [customers_id] => customer id
            [customers_name] => name
            [orders_status] => 0
            [currency_value] => yes
        )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [customers_id] => customer id
        [customers_name] => name
        [orders_status] => 1
        [currency_value] => no
    )
)
```

Comment: It's the first one and now that you've shown me this I realize why this is not an associative array and that i was over thinking what was going on here.  Thanks!